# Enter key handling in Dijit Editor

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using the Dijit.Editor for building a Mini RTE. The dijit editor uses the EnterKeyHandling plugin(dijit._editor.plugins.EnterKeyHanling), which only takes care of processing Enter keys in P or Div.

I want to extend this, to add in my own functionality for processing Enter keys in List elements, etc. Any suggestions on how I should approach this?

Answer (score 1):

This should actually be fairly easy.

Couple approaches you could take.

1) Monkey patch the existing EnterKeyHandling plugin.

Something like this:

```
var oldFunc = dijit._editor.plugins.EnterKeyHandling.prototype.onKeyPressed;
dijit._editor.plugins.EnterKeyHandling.prototype.onKeyPressed = function(){

// Do your stuff ...

oldFunc(arguments);

// Do your stuff ...

}
```

2) Create your own plugin, use EnterKeyHandling as a template/base class
You could just cut and paste the EnterKeyHandling source and give it your own name, and then hack the onKeyPressed method to do what you want.

But better is to subclass it and use that instead of the standard plugin:

```
dojo.declare("so.MyEnterHandling", dijit._editor.plugins.EnterKeyHandling, {
  onKeyPressed: function(){
     // Do your stuff
     // Either use EnterKeyHandling.onKeyPressed() as a template, or call:
     this.super(arguments);
  }
}
```

And then use it like any other plugin:

```
plugins = "['so.MyEnterHandling']"
```

NOTE: Code samples haven't been run, just typed into SO